# Is any function in yang model or xpath to get a current date time

Tags: xpath, ietf-netmod-yang

Please, can anyone tell me how to get current date and time in yang model, i want to apply a must statement in yang which validates that the entered date and time must greater than the current date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no XPath function to obtain current time in YANG. From [RFC 6020, 6.4.1 XPath Context](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-6.4.1):

> The function library is the core function library defined in [XPATH](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116), and a function "current()" that returns a node set with the initial context node.

The core function library contains no such function.

Your requirement is a bit odd. Are you sure you would want to constrain a datastore in such a way? If a value were to be modeled this way in a router config, for example, the operator of this router would have to keep updating this config to make it valid.